# Why "User Defined Type Not Defined" Error while running recursive function

Tags: excel, vba, recursion

This is a code which I use to check if a certain project folder is available or not in my directory.

```
Option Explicit
Public xCell As Range

Sub TestR()
Dim xTxt As String
Dim Rg As Range


xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set Rg = Application.InputBox("Please select project to check status!!!      ", "Lmtools", xTxt, , , , , 8)
If Rg Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Nothing selected!!!")
    Exit Sub
End If
For Each xCell In Rg
   If xCell.Value <> "" Then
      Call Recurse("D:\")
   End If
Next

End Sub

Function Recurse(sPath As String) As String

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFolder As Object
Dim mySubFolder As Object
Dim xStatus As String

Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)

For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.subfolders
    xStatus = mySubFolder.path
    If xStatus Like "*?\" & xCell.Value Then
        Cells(xCell.Row, xCell.Column + 1).Value = "Completed"
        Cells(xCell.Row, xCell.Column + 2).Value = xStatus
        GoTo nextiteration
    ElseIf xStatus Like "*?\" & xCell.Value & "\?*" Then
        Call reiterateFolder
    Else
        Cells(xCell.Row, xCell.Column + 1).Value = "Ongoing"
    End If
    Recurse = Recurse(mySubFolder.path)
Next

End Function
```

Now while I run The code, It throws an error saying that User Defined Type is not Defined.

Where have I made the mistake??

Comment: On what line is the error? - For this code to work you need to add a reference to the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* (Where FileSystemObject lives)

Comment: @AlexK. Its on the starting line of function Recurse...at `Function Recurse(sPath As String) As String`

Comment: @AlexK. How I can add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: In the VB editor, under *Tools* > *References* , check "Microsoft Scripting Runtime."

Comment: Thanks all. It worked after changing few lines.

Comment: `Call` is deprecated - so not to be used. Also `GoTo` has a real bad stink, especially if you `GoTo` a non-existent place!